# Pronunciation of $\in$-minimal

Tags: pronunciation

How do I pronounce $\in$-minimal? I need to know it to see whether I should write "$X$ has a $\in$-minimal element" or "$X$ has an $\in$-minimal element".

Comment: In such a context, $\in$ is often pronounced "epsilon" (in particular when speaking of $\in$-induction).

Comment: Apparently it even makes sense, if the claim from Wikipedia is true that $\in$ historically stems from $\epsilon$!